# Hot to add POST interceptor to aurelia http client

Tags: aurelia

Basically, the question says it all :). The scenario is as follows: I have some python models that are being passed between the browser, and the server. Python convention for naming things is to use underscores, and js convention is to camelCase everything. So I figured, I'd just create an http request interceptor to convert between python_models and jsModels. Is there a simple way to accomplish that?

I'm also looking for a way to do the inverse, so camelCase to that-case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `aurelia-http-client`, you can use a reviver.

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';  
import {Person} from './models';  
export class PersonService {  
  constructor(){
      this.http = new HttpClient().configure(x=> {
        x.withReviver((k,v) => {        
          return typeof v === 'object' ? new Person(v) : v;
        });  
    });
  }
  getPeople(){
      return this.http.get('/people');
  }
}
```

This only works for `aurelia-http-client` and not `aurelia-fetch-client`. It has been talked about in the `fetch` spec, but I don't believe it is currently implemented.

Check the following for more information:

- [(my) Best Practices in Aurelia: The Model](http://patrickwalters.net/my-best-practices-for-aurelia-solving-the-m-in-mvvm/)
- https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/104

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm also trying to do the inverse. So is there a way to hook into http client before it sends a request?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one, sorry. :(

Comment: Actually,  the process is really simple. You put me on the right track :). I just had to place `withInterceptor` call while configuring http client, and then transform the `response` object.